# Database Design: How to record bundle product deliveries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I’m adding bundle functionality to checkout where users can select their own custom bundle of products at a discounted price. As a result, the number of products in a bundle is dynamic.

I have the following existing DB schema:

Product (id (PK), name, price, etc….)
Transaction (id (PK), amount, datetime, etc….)
Delivery (id (PK), transaction_id (FK transaction.id), product_id (FK product.id), discount, etc….)

**Hypothetical Situation**

Bundle A - products (1,2)
Bundle B - products (3,4)

A transaction has both bundle A and B. Products (1,2,3,4) are delivered with the same transaction_id.

This being the case, with the current DB schema there is no way to know the following:
1. Was a product delivered as part of a bundle
2. What other products was a product bundled with

Adding a BOOL ‘bundle’ column to the delivery table will identify which products delivered in the transaction were in a bundle and which were not, but if a transaction contains multiple bundles, there’s no way of knowing which products were bundled together.

Transaction specific bundle ID’s could be created. Bundle A (ID 1), Bundle B (ID 2) that are unique to the transaction and recorded against each bundled product delivered. This seems like an odd way of doing it though. This then raises the question:

Should a bundle ID be unique across all transactions? And if so, would you just simply create a bundles table for the sole purpose of creating a unique bundle ID?

What do you think is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, I would consider a product hierarchy.

```
dbo.ProductHierarchy 
ProductHierarchyID INT (PK), ParentProductID INT (FK), ChildProductID INT (FK)
```

This way you can add Bundle A as a product (parent), and link it to its inclusive products 1 & 2 as children.

You could expand this schema to include a bundle price, which you can use to override the price point of product 1 and 2 when the bundle product is added to the order/transaction.  You can also include start/end dates for the promotion to control what appears on the front end.

Be careful when multiple parent bundles include similar child products however.

Ex. Customer Orders Product 1,2,3.  Bundle A is on product 1+2.  Bundle C is on product 1+3.  Do you let this customer get both bundles?  Or only one?

Another option is an offers table, which becomes an FKey on your products table, but then you end up blowing out products, all with the same name, just with different corresponding offer ids.